# Android Java Reload

Tags: java, android, refresh, reload

I have a minutes counter in my app.
It works so far, but it does not update, like going from minute 2 to minute 1.
How do I solve this issue or reload the app every minute.
code:

```
    // date format
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    // current date time
    String now = format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    // deadline01
    String dateStopJuli01 = "22/08/2015 21:10:00";

        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;
       try {
        d1 = format.parse(now);
        d2 = format.parse(dateStopJuli01);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();


        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;

((TextView) android.findViewById(R.id.test)).setText(diffMinutes);
```

Comment: Please add more details or some code... Do you use a CountDownTimer?

Comment: I see a d2 in your code but where/what is it initialized to? I don't see.

Comment: I edited forgot to write